# Is it possible to retain screen in @react-navigation/stack?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm currently using `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` to keep two screens in memory, but I want to have `@react-navigation/stack` functionality to customize transitions. Is it possible to retain to screens component in memory with `@react-navigation/stack`?

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate on a stack using `react-navigation`, here's what happens:

1. A new screen starts transitioning on top of the current screen.
2. The new screen completes the transition and is now "focused".
3. The previous screen remains "in memory", meaning it is not unmounted.
4. When navigating back, the same thing happens in reverse and the top-most screen does get unmounted.

**TL;DR** screens in the back-stack are not unmounted, but navigating back will unmount the top-most screen.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, which explains better what I need. I need keep screen in memory on back action.